# Render Dynamic content based on data filter - AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

We currently have our subscriber data sitting in the data extensions section, from there data filters have been created to segment the main audience into smaller pieces to facilitate certain send parameters and audience segmentation.

I want to dynamically display either of 2 images based on if they belong to a particular data filter.

1. Do I need to create actual audiences from the data filters, if so how, can you link a reference, please?
2. I've mocked up the piece of AMPscript below to facilitate, not sure how to check if they are a member of a data filter though?

```
%%[
    Var @member
    //Need code to check if they belong to a data extension

    IF @member THEN
]%%
    <img src="Image1.jpg" />
%%[ ELSE ]%%
    <img src="Image2.jpg" />
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to send the data filter audience, then no, [you don't have to create an activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_filter_scenario.htm&type=5) to populate a data extension.  You just won't see any pre-send counts. 
The refresh of the audience will happen automatically before the send occurs.

Retrieving a value from your send context is simple.  You had most of it already.  Assuming the `Member` value is a Boolean field and exists in the data extension you're filtering, you could do something like this:

```
%%[
    var @member
    set @member = AttributeValue("Member")

    IF @member == "true" THEN
]%%

    <img src="Image1.jpg" />

%%[ ELSE ]%%

    <img src="Image2.jpg" />

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

A drawback to sending to filtered audiences is that you can only select a single send audience in your Send Definition -- so keep that in mind.

**Reference**:

- [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)